# Burnt felt pad in Whirlpool dryer - remove or replace?

Tags: electrical, dryer

[image]

Opened my Whirlpool electric dryer to clean out the lint vent and found this.  Is this supposed to be here?  If so, should it be burnt.  I also found a few loose screws on the floor of the dryer so am wondering if this was something that was supposed to be removed during manufacturing that was forgotten.

Comment: That looks like a heat barrier pad that has fallen out of some strategic Location. Would be wise to do a little research to find out where it belongs.

Comment: What model is the dryer in question?

Comment: Hi did you ever find out what it is ? I found this in my dryer when cleaning it and ended up losing it . I can’t find anywhere what this would be , I even called the company that makes my dryer and they had no idea what I was talking about . I’m scared that I may have broken my dryer